# rest api design for bulk post

Tags: rest, api, api-design

Is it OK for an API to accept either an object or an array on the same endpoint?

I want to allow the user to post multiple items at once. I am thinking of creating a different endpoint, but then it gets hard with the semantics. Maybe prefixing the relevant handler with bulk would do it.

I thought that maybe the user can either post an object or an array to the same endpoint, and based on what it is, a different operation is performed.

I do not find any good examples on how something like this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is OK if you document it appropriately. But this might not be a good idea, and HTTP/2 makes such considerations largely unnecessary.

Bulk operations differ fundamentally from individual operations when you considers how errors shall be managed. For example, consider two objects A and B, though the client is not authorized to access object B. If we perform individual requests, the request regarding object B might get a 403 Forbidden error:

```
> POST /endpoint
>
> {"object": "A"}

< 200 OK

> POST /endpoint
>
> {"object": "B"}

< 403 Forbidden
```

But what should a bulk request do?

```
> POST /endpoint
>
> [{"object": "A"}, {"object": "B"}]

< ???
```

Should the server return a 200 OK status because one object could be processed? Or should it return a 403 Forbidden status because access to one object was not authorized? If one object doesn't validate, should operations on other objects still be performed?

Batch operations are difficult because they must answer these questions. The semantics of batch operations are fundamentally different from individual operations.

Often, this problem is resolved by always returning a 2xx status for batch operations, but returning an object that provides detailed status about sub-operations. For example:

```
> POST /endpoint
>
> [ {"object": "A", "result-id": "f3f9f318-28e8-44dd-99ac-f3d6c6ffd8bd"}
> , {"object"" "B", "result-id": "f778bc5e-b6e0-4be9-8a62-4dcb4912b70c"}
> ]

< 200 OK
<
< { "f3f9f318-28e8-44dd-99ac-f3d6c6ffd8bd": {"status": 200}
< , "f778bc5e-b6e0-4be9-8a62-4dcb4912b70c": {"status": 403}
< }
```

Because this is so different from a normal response, it is probably a good idea to keep batch APIs separate from individual APIs.

The style of responses I'm suggesting above is not very REST-y though, and in essence re-implements some features of HTTP. This might be appropriate in the context of HTTP/1 or HTTP/1.1. However, HTTP/2 supports native multiplexing. Multiple concurrent requests are roughly as efficient as a single batch request. But the individual requests might be much simpler to reason about, unless the batch request has some specific meaning in the context of your business logic (e.g. changes that must be applied atomically in a transaction).

So if you're considering to offer a batch API purely for performance reasons, consider using HTTP/2 instead. Client support for HTTP/2 is good. Web framework support is not as good, but unnecessary: you can probably use a reverse proxy like Nginx that translates a stream of HTTP/2 requests into separate HTTP/1.1 requests. This style of architecture preserves the latency benefits of using HTTP/2 for concurrent requests.

Comment: How would you name a separate bulk endpoint, then? `POST /bulk/endpoint` ? I have implemented this one in go but its really for batching. https://gist.github.com/bluebrown/f0401fd7c1941985101a35085c041502. My question here is is for bulk of the same resource. The thing with http/2 sounds reasonable. I may want to look into that.

Comment: @TheFool That batch handler is quite clever! But unless this also provides advantages like transactional changes it's a roundabout way to re-implement HTTP/2 features. Go has pretty good support for newer HTTP versions. Your batch handler can receive multiple sub-requests with different operations so it can't have a more useful name than `/batch` or similar. But a bulk endpoint for a specific operation might have a meaningful name in the application domain. Otherwise, not a fan of `/bulk/endpoint` since it suggests a hierarchy that isn't there – I'd prefer `/bulk-endpoint` or `/endpoint?bulk`.